# How do I prove that $e^t,te^t,e^{-t} $ are linearly independent?

Tags: linear-algebra

In $\mathbb R^\mathbb R$, consider $\varphi_1(t)=e^t,\varphi_2(t)=te^t,\varphi_3(t)=e^{-t} $ for each $t \in \mathbb R$.

How do I prove that $\varphi_1,\varphi_2,\varphi_3$ are linearly independent?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wronskian.

Comment: Three such functions are independent if and only if $Ae^t+ Bte^t+ Ce^{-5}= 0$, for all t, implies that A= B= C= 0.  In order to determine the three numbers, A, B, and C, you need three equations.  One way to do that is set t to three different values.  t= 0 is particularly easy: $e^0= 1$ so the equation becomes $A+ C= 0$.  Another way to get two more equations is to take the first and second derivatives and set t= 0.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint/method:

Write down a hypothetical linear combination that's $0$. Then substitute some values of $t$ to  get an inconsistent set of linear equations for the three coefficients.

Answer (score 4):

The Wronskian of $\varphi_1$, $\varphi_2$, $\varphi_3$, given by $$W(\varphi_1,\varphi_2,\varphi_3) = \begin{vmatrix}\varphi_1 & \varphi_2 & \varphi_3 \\ \varphi'_1 & \varphi'_2 & \varphi'_3 \\\varphi''_1 & \varphi''_2 & \varphi''_3 \\\end{vmatrix}$$ can be used to determine if the three functions are linearly independent. If $W(\varphi_1, \varphi_2, \varphi_3) = 0$, then you have linear **dependence**. Otherwise, you have linear independence.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $ae^t +bte^t + c e^{-t} = 0$ for all $t\in\mathbb R.$ Divide by $e^t$ to see $a+bt+ce^{-2t}=0.$ If $b\ne 0,$ we have an infinite limit at $\infty,$ contradiction. So $b=0.$ We then see $a+ce^{-2t}=0.$ As $t\to \infty,$ this $\to a.$ Thus $a=0.$ So we're left with $ce^{-2t}=0,$ which implies $c=0.$

Answer (score 0):

Solve the System
$$\lambda_1e+\lambda_2e+\lambda_3e^{-1}=0$$
$$\lambda_1e^2+\lambda_22e^2+\lambda_3e^{-2}=0$$
$$\lambda_1e^3+\lambda_23e^3+\lambda_3e^{-3}=0$$

Answer (score 0):

Three such functions are independent if and only if $Ae^t+ Bte^t+ Ce^{-t}= 0$, for all t, implies that A= B= C= 0.  In order to determine the three numbers, A, B, and C, you need three equations.  One way to do that is set t to three different values.  t= 0 is particularly easy: $e^0= 1$ so the equation becomes $A+ C= 0$.  Another way to get two more equations is to take the first and second derivatives and set t= 0.  The first derivative is Ae^t+ B(1+ t)e^t- Ce^{-t}= 0.  For t= 0 that gives $A+ B- C= 0$. The second derivative is $Ae^t+ B(2+ t)e^t+ Ce^{-t}= 0$.  For t= 0 that gives $A+ 2B+ C= 0$.
Solve the three equations A+ C= 0, A+ B- C= 0, and A+ 2B+ C= 0.  The functions are independent if and only if the only solution is A= B= C= 0.